# Wordpress blog loop with php

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, blogs

I have a problem with Wordpress. I am currently using Bootstrap and PHP to create a blog loop.

This is what we have so far:

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="container-fluid">

    <?php query_posts('posts_per_page='); ?>
    <!-- <?php //query_posts('posts_per_page=3&cat=6&post_type=our_services'); ?> -->

    <div class="row">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">


<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ); ?>

    <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" alt="<?php the_title() ?>">

                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h3>

            </div><!-- col -->

         <?php } ?>

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

         </div><!-- row -->

    </div><!-- container -->
</section><!-- services -->

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

This code produces three posts and they currently loop. However, I want four posts in the loop where the fourth post is bigger as if it's "featured" in the blog, so it's supposed to be bigger than the other posts and at the top.

Answer (score 0):

You can change while to for or introduce an external counter as a basic idea
e.g

```
   $i = 0;
    while ( have_posts() ) {
     $i++;
     ($i == 4) ?  echo "<div class='featured-post'>".the_post()."</div>" : the_post();
    }
```

You should add `col-lg-12` to take the whole space. If you are using Bootstrap 4 you can use `order-lg-*` to reverse the order of post with CSS.

Excuse me if there are syntax errors it's been a long since I wrote PHP.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't really work out. Not sure how this code correlates with mine. I've tried to work it in, but still doesn't work. Not sure if it's because I'm doing something wrong or if there's a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Im trying to achieve the same as you Yazan.

This is my code:

```
<?php get_header(); 
$postCount = 1;
?>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : $postCount++; ?>

<?php if($postCount == 2) { ?>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">

<?php } else { ?>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">

<?php } ?>

    <h3 class="flexcenter"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h3>

    </div><!-- col -->

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

    </div><!-- row -->
</div><!-- container -->
```

The outcome of this code is Visually correct. The first post is col-12 and the rest of them is col-4.

But the problem is that it loops out the same post..

**UPDATE**

It turns out I needed to use Wp-query - now it works - the only problem I'm having now is to loop in a row every third post after the first post.

Here is the code:

```
<?php get_header(); 
$postCount = 1;
$args = array( 'post_type' => '' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

<?php if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

    <?php if($postCount == 1) { ?>

    <div class="heropost flexcolumn col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12" 
    style="
    background:
    linear-gradient( rgba(15, 21, 36, 0.6), rgba(250, 55, 122, 0.6) ),
    url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>);
    ">

    <div class="featuredtitle">
        <h6 class="pretitle">Featured</h6>
    </div>

    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <a class="button hvr-ripple-out" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><span>Läs nyheten</span></a>

    </div><!-- col -->

    <?php } else { ?>


    <div class="smallpost col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 flexcolumn">

    <div class="postloop-image"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></div>
    <div class="post-category"><?php the_category(); ?></div>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

    </div><!-- col -->

    <?php } ?>

    <?php $postCount++; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

</div><!-- row -->

</div><!-- container -->

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**So it's not correct yet!**

Comment: Hmm interesting... I've been trying to experiment with similar code, but haven't been able to figure it out yet...